# Random padding for rows using List in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

In SwiftUi I have a list with dates.

There is padding to the left of each list item that I can't figure out how to correct....

[image: See image]

This is my body view

```
   var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0){
    NavigationView {
      
        List{
            
             ForEach(calObject.dateArray,id: \.self){date in
             
            DateRow(date: date)
            
             }
            
        }.navigationBarTitle("\(calObject.nameOfMonth(calObject.stepper))")
            
    }
}
```

And this is my DateRow view

```
struct DateRow: View {
@ObservedObject private var calObject = CalendarObject()


var date: Date


var body: some View {
        HStack(){
      
        
            Text(calObject.rowDateFormatter(date).prefix(3)).bold()
                   .foregroundColor(.white)
                   .padding()
                   .background(Color.gray)
                   .mask(Circle())
                .padding(.trailing)
            
       
            Text("\(calObject.rowDateFormatter(date))")
        
          Spacer()
          
    
        
        }
        
    }
```

Somebody who can help me with this really frustrating situation? =/

Comment: that is the default behaviour of List, You have to use Scroll view for that purpose? better with LazyVStack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove .padding(.trailing) from text so all elements will have equal space

```
struct DateRow: View {
@ObservedObject private var calObject = CalendarObject()


var date: Date


var body: some View {
    HStack(){
  
    
        Text(calObject.rowDateFormatter(date).prefix(3)).bold()
               .foregroundColor(.white)
               .padding()
               .background(Color.gray)
               .mask(Circle())
               .frame(width: 45, height: 45)     
   
        Text("\(calObject.rowDateFormatter(date))")
    
      Spacer()
      

    
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Babar, this fixed the alignment issue, now I noticed when I switched locale some characters made the circle bigger or smaller so I switched and used a stack instead of a mask.



 `ZStack {
                            Circle()
                                .fill(Color.secondary)
                                .frame(width: 45, height: 45)

                    Text(calObject.rowDateFormatter(date).prefix(2)).bold()
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                        }`

Comment: updated my answer, u just need to fix circle frame instead of using ZStack

Comment: if u think my answer is correct please mark it answered